# Remotely zipping files with PowerShell start-process and invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, start-process

I want to be able to remote into a system and zip or unzip files there and have the process signal when it is complete.  Start-process works with the -wait parameter to run 7z.exe synchronously from PowerShell.  When I try to combine that with invoke-command to run the same command remotely, it does not honor the wait parameter and I believe it is killing the process since it returns quickly and never produces a zip file.

```
[string]$sevenZip = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"
[Array]$arguments = "a", $zipFilename, $dirToZip;

"Starting $sevenZip with $arguments"
Start-Process $sevenZip "$arguments" -Wait
#blocks and waits for zip file to complete
```

I originally tried the PSCX write-zip & expand-archive, but the latter is not compatible with 64-bit .NET 4.0 configuration.  So now I'm trying to call 64-bit 7z.exe through the command line.  I'm not receiving any errors.  PowerShell reports the job as running state and then complete, and no zip file is produced.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -FilePath 'C:\Scripts\ZipIt.ps1' -ArgumentList    'd:\TestFolder','d:\promote\TestFile.7z' -AsJob
```

Appreciate any help or pointers.

Thanks,
Gregory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Start-Process will be used synchronously here, I would recommend avoiding it and just use the `7z.exe` executable:

```
$sevenZip = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"
&$sevenZip a $zipFileName $dirToZip
```

Doing so will naturally block your script until 7zip completes its job.

Comment: Thank you Efran.  That worked!  I did run into a memory issue but fixed it by increasing from the 150MB default.

winrm set winrm/config/winrs `@`{MaxMemoryPerShellMB=`"255`"`}

Answer (score 0):

Using 7z.exe directly would do the trick. If you find you need to **unzip** a password protected file you could use:

```
$sevenZip = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"
&$sevenZip e -y  "-o$dirToUnZip" -psomepassword $dirToUnZip\$zipFileName
```